# perl script to convert the string EXP501.1-01.0 to EXP501_01

Tags: regex, string, perl

I want to convert the string

> EXP501.1-01.0

to

> EXP501_01

That means `-01`, `-02`, `-03`... are incremental and I want to append that same number which is in first string next to the `_` of the second string (which will be parsed on the basis of the first string).

Comment: I changed some text formatting, highlighted some numbers and added two relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    my $string = "EXP501.1-01.0";
    $short = substr($string, 0, -7);
    $new = substr($string,8,-2);
    my $str = $short . $new;
    $str =~ s/ - /_/g; # Replace all " - " with "_"
    $str =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g; # Replace all non-alphanumericals with "_"

    print $str . "\n";
```

Comment: @ManjunathS: On SO, if you find that an answer has helped you, it is considered polite to accept it.